# Uncheck My billing and shipping address are the same checkbox in Create New Order Admin Section

Tags: magento2

I am working on Magento ver. 2.4.2

. I want to uncheck My billing and shipping address are the same checkbox in  in Create New Order Admin Section.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the **address.phtml** File and remove the checked attribute in **line no. 79**

```
<?php if ($block->getIsAsBilling()): ?>checked<?php endif; ?> />
```

To override the `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/form/address.phtml` file in Magento 2, you can follow these steps:

1. Create a new module or use an existing one. Let's assume the module is called **MyCompany_MyModule**.
2. Create a new file at `app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml` with the following content:

   ```
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
          <referenceBlock name="order_create_billing_address">
             <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">MyCompany_MyModule::order/create/form/address.phtml</argument>
             </action>
          </referenceBlock>
          <referenceBlock name="order_create_shipping_address">
             <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">MyCompany_MyModule::order/create/form/address.phtml</argument>
             </action>
          </referenceBlock>
       </body>
    </page>
   ```
3. Create a new file at `app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/form/address.phtml` and copy the contents of the original address.phtml file there.
4. Make any changes you want to the copied **address.phtml** file.
5. Flush the cache to see the changes in effect.

Comment: Not working  if again check the button not working as default